Nexus version upgrade casuing the whole scope go corrupt - missing metadata of the scope/package
If I deploy a version 1.0.0 it gets deployed and works fine. The below link gives all the metadata which is used to download the package.
http://nexus/repository/my-nexus-repository/@my-scope%2fpackage-name
The response is
{"_id":"@my-scope/package-name","name":"@my-scope/package-name","description":"Some package description",
"dist-tags":{"latest":"1.0.0"},"versions":{"1.0.0":{"name":"@my-scope/package-name","version":"1.0.0",
"description":"","main":"./dist/index.js","scripts":{"build":"tsup",
"test":"echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1","postinstall":"node main.js"}
,"keywords":["\"Validate","JSON\"","\"Validate","interface\""],"author":{"name":"Sagar"},
"license":"ISC","devDependencies":{"ts-node":"^10.9.2","tsup":"^8.0.2","typescript":"^5.4.3"},
"dependencies":{"ajv":"^6.12.6","ajv-openapi":"2.0.0","sdui":"github:scope/some-repo",
"ts-json-schema-generator":"2.0.0"},"_id":"@my-scope/package-name@1.0.0","readme":"ERROR: No README data found!",
"gitHead":"","types":"./dist/index.d.ts","_nodeVersion":"18.20.0","_npmVersion":"10.5.0",
"dist":{"integrity":"removedforstackoverflow",
"shasum":"removedforstackoverflow",
"tarball":"http://nexus/repository/repo-name/@my-scope/package-name/-/package-name-1.0.0.tgz"}}}}



But If I publish a new version 1.0.1, my both the version go corrupt, likely my whole scope gets corrupt as the above link only gives me the package id in the metadata
http://nexus/repository/my-nexus-repository/@my-scope%2fpackage-name

The response is {"_id":"@my-package/package-name"}


Just trying the publish a new package using command 

npm publish --registry=http://nexus-dev.name.in:8080/repository/repo-name

The new package was reflecting on nexus just the metadata used to go away

